# can we use object for accessing for a static member?

Tags: java

As per my knowledge, static members can be accessed directly. But if someone wants to access it by creating object of it, is this possible in Java?

Comment: NO, IT IS NOT JAVA. It is Java.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

As the others said, it is possible.

But you shouldn't do it, because it is error prone. Using the class for static access, it is easy to recognize what you meant to do, but if you use the object, one could think, that you want to access a field.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is **possible**, but such a need should ideally NEVER arrive. If it does, check your object design again.

Static methods, by definition, **should be** accessed via the class reference.

Take a read through this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 1):

Well surely. You can even do the following:

```
Foo foo = null;
foo.staticMethod();
```

But it's kind of pointless and will result in warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is *possible* but you'll get a warning for it, and there is absolutely no reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To put it shortly, yes, it's possible, but I don't see any reason to do it (if all you want is to access the static member).

Comment: Yes, even if your class does not extend any other class, it is implicitly extended from java.lang.Object.